# Z-index on nested absolute elements to overlap similar absolute elements?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrQG6/

HTML

```
<div id='map'>
    <div class='hotspot' id='hs1'>
        <div class='info-window'>
            Foobar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='hotspot' id='hs2'>
        <div class='info-window'>
            Foobar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hotspot {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
} 
.info-window {
    display: none;
    height: 250px;
     width: 250px;   
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}​
```

The `.hotspot` elements show in the container. The `.info-window` elements do not show by default. Clicking a `.hotspot` will display its corresponding `.info-window`. However, I want the `.info-window` to cover any `.hotspot` elements underneath it.

Instead, `.hotspot` elements are on *top* of the `.info-window` element. Conceptually, I'm misunderstanding the use of `position` and `z-index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing

```
z-index: 10;
```

from your .hotspot I believe it solves your problem.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrQG6/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `.info-window` elements are inside `.hotspot` elements, both of which have equal `z-index`. Imagine this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Since we set the two `<div>`s with equal `z-index` values, then they have equal levels. The second, by default, overlaps the first just because of order in the markup.

Now, consider this:

```
<div><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

No matter what `z-index` you give the first `.inner` element, it will always be underneath the second `<div>` container, just because of the fact that the first `.inner` element's `<div>` container *is already underneath the second*.

It's like trying to jump as high as you can from the first floor of a building: you'll never get higher than the second floor no matter how high you jump because you'll eventually hit the ceiling, which will prevent you from going any higher.[1]

A better approach would be to use more or less the same markup:

```
<div class="hotspot">
    <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

and use more or less the same CSS rules on `.hotspot`:

```
.hotspot {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}

.hotspot .info {
    display:none;
}
```

but then, introduce a flag class that overrides that:

```
.hotspot.active {
    z-index:20; /* let's raise this a bit */
}

.hotspot.active .info {
    display:block;
}
```

then manipulate that with Javascript:

```
var hotspots = $('.hotspot').on('click', function (e) {
    hotspots.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: [1] : unless you're the f*ckin' Hulk, which kinda makes this analogy moot.

Comment: +1 I greatly appreciate the explanation. I've experimented with this and better understand the z-index property with nested elements.

Comment: With the accepted answer, its as simple as not specifying a z-index for the `.hotspot`. Is there a disadvantage to this? I specified one in the first place so that it is definitely on *top* of the `#map`.

Comment: The only disadvantage I can think of is *not specifying a z-index* in the first place. Will this affect your layout? I can't really answer that for you. :D If removing the `z-index` corrects it for you sufficiently, then go with that. There are cases where you *have* to specify a `z-index`, and only you can identify those situations.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `z-index` property for the parent elements, currently they both have the same z-index value.

```
#hs1 { 
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}    
#hs2 { 
    top: 150px;
    left: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMj8S/

Answer (score 1):

Because your infobox is a child of your hotspot div, youll have to affect the zIndex of the containers ala:

```
$('.hotspot').click(function() {
    $('.hotspot').css('zIndex', 1);  //Force all hotspots to the back
    $(this).css('zIndex', 9999);  //force this hotspot to the front
    $('.info-window').hide();  //Hide all infoboxes, in case of overlap
    $(this).find('.info-window').show();     //show the infobox inside this div
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrQG6/3/

Answer (score 1):

The core issue at play here is CSS stacking contexts, which are more tricky to get your head around than they look at first glance.

`#hs2` appears above the`.info-window` in `#hs1` even though its z-index value is lower than that of `.info-window` because the `.info-window` is a descendant of `#hs1`, which established a new stacking context.

Here are a couple of good links if you want to read up on this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context), [very good blog article by Tim Kadlec](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/)